# boolean graphics c++ (xcode mac)

Tags: c++

I am generating expressions in c++ consisting of 1's and 0's.
The expressions are 100*100 characters (that's 100 lines with 100 characters each)

Is there a simple way to display these expressions visually?
A good ASCII-character like a black and a white box, or a simple picture format?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format is really easy to generate

Comment: Yeah. On the Mac you can easily use `ppm2tiff` to visualize your file.

Comment: Put answers into answers please, even if they are just one sentence long so the user can accept it. Thx.